# sbt-stylus with Fluidity

Tags: sbt, stylus, sbt-web

With the Stylus cli, I am able to add  @import fluidity to my .styl files, and then define the path to the Fluidity distribution:

```
stylus src/main/assets/styles  --use node_modules/fluidity/lib/fluidity --out target/web/css
```

But I can't figure out how to get sbt-stylus to do something similar to support Fluidity.  Looking at the code, it appears that --compress is the only cli option currently supported.  I can (try to) fork sbt-stylus and add support for 'uses', but I want to first see if I'm just missing something, or if work has already been dome somewhere.